# How CryptoNote protocol protects Monero users?

Tags: cryptonote, protocol, stealth-address

We can read that Monero possesses significant algorithmic for blockchain obfuscation.
In what way it protects users from reading the data from the blockchain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main protections from Cryptonote: Untraceability ( provided by Ring Signatures ) and Unlinkability ( provided by Stealth addresses ).

Detailed information in the [Cryptonote website](https://cryptonote.org/inside#untraceable-payments).

Monero went further following [researchers](http://lab.getmonero.org) recommendation and added a forced minimum of 2 [mixing](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/ringsignatures) for a transaction ( to be bumped to 4 ) and is going to implement [Confidential Transactions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1098.pdf) in the near future further obfuscating the already hard to guess exact amount of coins in a determined transaction.